# Angular 2: array.splice() is removing the elements from DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an html table and it has default checked rows.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Initial</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let name of names; let i = index">
        <td><input type="checkbox" [checked]="chk" (change)="onTaChange(name, $event.target.checked,i)"></td>
        <td>{{name.id}}</td>
        <td>{{name.Fname}}</td>
        <td>{{name.Initial}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm forming one more array for to contain unchecked/checked objects. So in onTaChange() method I'm passing the index in splice() and want to remove the object at that index(unchecked row in the table). But rows(objects) are getting removed if I uncheck even though they both are different arrays of objects.

What I want is, have a second array with only checked/unchecked rows of objects. Any help on this?

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DD1EqbtVwy2VFA9zbR1d?p=preview)

Comment: I don't get it, you want to remove them but not remove them / ?

Comment: `alteredNames:string[]=this.names;` causes `alteredNames` to reference the same array - it does not create a copy -> any modifications to `alteredNames` are also happening on `names`

Answer (score 1):

**Reason** :Arrays keep their references ie. when you are creating following :

alteredNames:string[]=this.names;

alteredNames is not a new Array but a reference to the original array, hence whatever you do in either array will reflect in both.

**Solution** : Make a deep copy of the array. Use  _.cloneDeep(this.name)

Comment: `angular.copy` is part of AngularJS, not Angular2

Answer (score 1):

By copying an array, there are many modern ways like:

- `loop`
- `Array.from`
- `Array.slice`
- `Array.concat`
- `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr))`
- `[...arr]` from ES6

But most of them are not creating new instance for the new array except for `loop` or `Array.concat()`.
So, In your case, you have to use the loop way by using `Array.forEach` and `Array.push` or by `Array.concat()` to copy the array.

This is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/455adsp0D1PvgnFQrlEJ?p=preview) for you. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same reference and you are sending the entire array to your OnTaChange method

The native `slice()` method is also used to clone the array object

```
this.alteredNames=this.names.slice(0);
```

Also as Pankaj said,

```
this.alteredNames=Object.assign([], this.names)
```

Apart from the above, one awesome 3rd party library can also be used to achieve the same results,

```
  export class App {
  chk:boolean = true;
  names:string[] = [
    {
      "Fname": "Bunty",
      "id": "1",
      "Initial":"G"
    },
    {
      "Fname": "Ronny",
      "id": "2",
      "Initial":"K"
    },
    {
      "Fname": "Sam",
      "id": "3",
      "Initial":"P"
    },
    {
      "Fname": "James",
      "id": "4",
      "Initial":"M"
    }
    ];
    alteredNames:string[];
  constructor() {
   this.alteredNames=_.clone(this.names) //////////this works
   // or
   this.alteredNames=_.cloneDeep(this.names) // will also work. 
  }

  onTaChange(name:string, $event.target.checked:boolean,i:number){
    if(!checked){
      this.alteredNames.splice(i,1); 
      console.log(this.alteredNames);
    }
    else{
      this.alteredNames.push(name);
    }
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You should include lodash from this [CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js) as below

**[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JIVkWETkvG24rmEEvxLl?p=preview)**

Also,

Comment: even `Object.assign([], this.names)` should work instead of `_.clone`

Comment: are you sure that the result is right?the index was changed after you deleted item from the `alteredItems` but index on `onChange` never changed.

Comment: This is only removing the objects and not adding back if I check the row again after unchecking

Comment: @Protagonist its because you didn't handle the other condition, down voted? reason? **Your post was about the DOM element getting removed.**

Comment: @holi-java what was your question?

Comment: @Aravind `names` in table unchecked not delete `alteredItem` correctly,because item that was deleted from `alteredItem`,a best practice should be add a flag property like `detached` and filtering the items from `alteredItem`

Comment: so what's you question. or you wanna convey something

Comment: @Aravind I have handled the other condition in else part. Its same like remove, I will add the array if its checked

Comment: @Protagonist right now I m at my work place. and I will fix anything by tonight